# Django variables won't render in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

**Django version 2.1.3**

**Python version 3.7**

Writing out sample code just to get an understanding of **Django**. Right now I'm on **Templates** and I'm having 0 luck when it come to rendering **variables**.

In `views.py` folder I've created a little dictionary and passed it through under the variable **content**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

posts = [
    {
    'Title': 'Challanger 1',
    'Name': 'Sammy',
    'Age': '33',
    'Food': 'Seafood'
    },   
    {
    'Title': 'Challanger 2',
    'Name': 'Sammy',
    'Age': '33',
    'Food': 'Seafood'
    }
]

def home(request):
    content = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', content)
```

In my `home.html`file, I've added a few **123** next to my `{{variable}}`to make sure the `.html` file is connecting to the `view.py`. When I `py manage.py runserver`, only the 123 is displayed but none of my `{{variables}}`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% for post in posts %}

        <p>123 {{ post.name }}</p>
        <h1>123  {{ post.title }}</h1>
        <h1>123 {{ post.age }}</h1>

    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

**localhost:8000** produces:

```
123

123
123
123

123
123
```

When I open view-source from the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>



        <p>123 </p>
        <h1>123  </h1>
        <h1>123 </h1>



        <p>123 </p>
        <h1>123  </h1>
        <h1>123 </h1>



</body>
</html>
```

Side note: When I'm in the `home.html` file I've noticed that only `{{post.title}}` and `{{post.name}}` auto-fill and `{{post.age}}` and `{{post.food}}` never auto-fill.

There are also times when I've deleted everything in the `home.html` file and none of the `{{variables}}` auto-fill when I rewrite out the code. Either way the ending result is still the same, variables wont load.

Comment: You have mentioned Name, Title , Age but in your html you are adding name, title, age

Answer (score 1):

You're using `post.name` (all lowercase) in the template, but you defined the dictionaries in the python code to have `Name` (uppercase N) as the key.

Try using `{{ post.Name }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem, Dictionary Keys Are Case-Sensitive.
try below code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        {% for post in posts %}

            <p>123 {{ post.Name }}</p>
            <h1>123  {{ post.Title }}</h1>
            <h1>123 {{ post.Age }}</h1>

        {% endfor %}

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Such a noob mistake. Thank you very much.